# how to Pass param to jsp:include

Tags: java, jsp

This is my part of jsp file.i am struggling to set param value to SalesClientDetails.jsp.i am not using  this style <% %>. How to pass param i tried using jsp:expression but no success.

```
<jsp:scriptlet>
    if (request.getParameter("clientid") != null) {
        String clientid = request.getParameter("clientid");
</jsp:scriptlet>

        <jsp:include page="SalesClientDetails.jsp">
            <jsp:param name="clientid" value= />
        </jsp:include>

<jsp:scriptlet>
    }
</jsp:scriptlet>
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple, do not use scriptlets, also not in flavor of JSP tags. Use [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)/[EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info).

```
<c:if test="${not empty param.clientid}">
    <jsp:include page="SalesClientDetails.jsp" />
</c:if>
```

And in the `SalesClientDetails.jsp` just get it by

```
${param.clientid}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've created the variable `clientId` within a scriptlet, which means that it's a Java variable (versus a value in the page context). So you have to retrieve it with `<%= %>`:

```
<jsp:param name="clientid" value="<%=clientId%>" />
```

Comment: Taking a second look at your code, I'm somewhat surprised that it compiles at all. Does it?